# Error on C# when trying to fetch multiple data from database

Tags: c#, sql, database, fetch

I have this code in C#:

```
 private void sqlConnLabel() 
 {
        NoIDPenghuni = new SqlParameter();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strCon);

        com2 = new SqlCommand();
        com2.Connection = con;
        con.Open();

        com2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        com2.CommandText = "label";

        NoIDPenghuni.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
        NoIDPenghuni.Size = 50;
        NoIDPenghuni.ParameterName = "@NoIDPenghuni";
        NoIDPenghuni.Value = NoIDPenghuniC;
        NoIDPenghuni.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

        com2.Parameters.Add(NoIDPenghuni);

        string NamaPenghuni;
        string JKPenghuni;
        string NoTelpPenghuni;
        string AlamatPenghuni;
        string NoKamar;

        NamaPenghuni = Convert.ToString(com2.ExecuteScalar());
        JKPenghuni = Convert.ToString(com2.ExecuteScalar());
        NoTelpPenghuni = Convert.ToString(com2.ExecuteScalar());
        AlamatPenghuni = Convert.ToString(com2.ExecuteScalar());
        NoKamar = Convert.ToString(com2.ExecuteScalar());

        SqlDataReader reader = com2.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            NamaPenghuni = reader["NamaPenghuni"] == DBNull.Value ? null : (string)reader["NamaPenghuni"];
            JKPenghuni = reader["JKPenghuni"] == DBNull.Value ? null : (string)reader["JKPenghuni"];
            NoTelpPenghuni = reader["NoTelpPenghuni"] == DBNull.Value ? null : (string)reader["NoTelpPenghuni"];
            AlamatPenghuni = reader["AlamatPenghuni"] == DBNull.Value ? null : (string)reader["AlamatPenghuni"];
            NoKamar = reader["NoKamar"] == DBNull.Value ? null : (string)reader["NoKamar"];
        }

        label9.Text = NoIDPenghuniC;
        label8.Text = NamaPenghuni;

        if (JKPenghuni == "P")
            label7.Text = "Male";
        else
            label7.Text = "Female";

        label6.Text = NoTelpPenghuni;
        label18.Text = AlamatPenghuni;

        label5.Text = NoKamar;
        con.Close();
    }
```

When I try to run it keeps telling me

> IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled.

I think the data won't be fetched into my C#. It only takes the *'NamaPenghuni'*

For example: if I take the data with *NoIDPenghuni='110801101*, the NamaPenghuni should be *Priska Hapsari*, the JKPenghuni should be *W*, the NoTelpPenghuni should be *08567711332*, and the AlamatPenghuni should be *Jl*. Mega Cinere No. 29, *Cinere*.

But on my locals section I can see that all those string variables values are Priska Hapsari.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Can you paste the sp code also? Maybe the reader has nothing to read at the final ExecuteReader.

Comment: Why do you call for 5 times the ExecuteScalar before the ExecuteReader?

Comment: @Steve because I want all the data fetch to the string.
Should I make a different function for each variable?

Answer (score 0):

You call for 5 times the ExecuteScalar before the ExecuteReader.
ExecuteScalar returns the first column of the first row (just one result).
Calling it 5 times results in the same value for the all 5 variables

The IndexOutOfRange exception could be caused by the following ExecuteReader that expects to find 5 columns in the returned values, but we can't see if the StoredProcedure returns effectively 5 values per row

Comment: because I want all the data fetch to the string. Should I make a different function for each variable?

Comment: Please explain. How many rows your stored procedure returns? Just one with five columns? If you could show the code of the SP we can better understand the problem. ExecuteScalar cannot be used to retrive the value of the second column, the correct way is ExecuteReader, but you need to return the exact columns expected by the reader["your_col_name_here"]

Comment: Thanks the problem is solved. I finally use execute scalar for each data.

Comment: Five calls to the database instead of one? Well if it is acceptable then all is good